# How to start a .Net Core 3.1 process from a .Net Core 3.1 process?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to start a child .Net Core 3.1 process from another .Net Core 3.1 process for anonymous pipe communication.

```
_childProcess = new Process();
_childProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "childProcess.exe";
_childProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
_childProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain?.BaseDirectory;
_childProcess.Start();
```

results in the error when debugging: "To run this application, you must install .Net Core".

[image: Error message popup]

The child process project is a dependency of the parent project which results in the `childProcess.exe` being copied into the output directory of the parent process. `childProcess.exe` can be started directly with no problem. When started from code the runtime cannot be found.

Comment: How did you start `childProcess.exe` directly?

Comment: Assuming that you're not using single files but rather using the installed .NET core, you could start `dotnet` instead and pass `childProcess` as the parameter

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I started it directly from FileExplorer, also works from command line.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I tried starting dotnet but the command could not be found, I can run dotnet from command line

Comment: Thank you everyone for your time. It was a silly mistake on my part. I was not copying the runtimeconfig files. Usually this results in a 'hostpolicy.dll' error but my project types (WorkerService for parent, AvaloniaUI for child) it was causing the error to manifest differently. I should have considered the project types.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `child.runtimeconfig.json' is in the same directory as the` client.exe`.

Comment: This or some other json file is missing - 90 percent case.